# how do i rank the first place

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

> I really need help with this little problem im having to rank the first person according to the highest score .

```
     //variables where the total value will go for each person  
            var musT = 0;
            var zikT = 0;
            var hamT = 0;

     // if the spacebar is pressed
     document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){

          //generate random integers between 1 and 12
            var person_0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);      
            var person_1= Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);      
            var person_2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);  

            // add total number of pushups
            musT += person_0;
            zikT += person_1;
            hamT += person_2;

            //displaying the total pushups
            $("#musT .box").html(musT);
            $("#zikT .box").html(zikT);
            $("#hamT .box").html(hamT);

            }
```

> I wanna rank the highest number in a better way

```
            //ranking the top person

            if(musT > zikT && hamT){
                $("#first").html("Musa: " + musT );
            } if(zikT > musT && hamT){
                $("#first").html("Zikria: " + zikT );

            } if(hamT > musT && zikT){
               $("#first").html("Hamza: " + hamT ); 

     }
 }
```

Comment: what are musa, zikria and hamza? where are you using person_0, person_1 and person_2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work the way you wrote it

```
if(musT > zikT && hamT){
   $("#first").html("Musa: " + musT );
} if(zikT > musT && hamT){
   $("#first").html("Zikria: " + zikT );
} if(hamT > musT && zikT){
   $("#first").html("Hamza: " + hamT );
```

Write it like this:

```
if(musT > zikT && musT > hamT){
   $("#first").html("Musa: " + musT );
} else if(zikT > musT &&  zikT > hamT){
   $("#first").html("Zikria: " + zikT );
} else if(hamT > musT && hamT > zikT){
   $("#first").html("Hamza: " + hamT );
```

This is also a bad way to do it. Instead of using if else condition try to store it in an array and get the maximum from that array.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could compare only two values `a > b`. If you want to compare more than one value you should do it like `a > b && a > c`. Also if you want to use complicated if-statements you should do it like

```
if(statement){
    //something
} else if (other thing..){
    // and so
} else if (statement3){
    // and so
} else {
    // this is the last case
}
```

You could have as many as you want if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close! The only problem is with your `if` conditionals. With your logic `musT > zikT && hamT` you're essentially just checking that `must` is greater than `zikT`, while `hamT` simply **exists**.

That's because the `&&` (AND) considers everything on either side of it to be a **separate condition**. Your above code would equate to `(musT > zikT) && (hamT)` with brackets.

Keeping that in mind, it's often easier to follow if you add the brackets in manually yourself, as in the following working example. It's also important to use **`else if`** statements so that you don't accidentally trigger **more than one** of your conditionals.

Don't forget that's it's also possible that **all** numbers are **the same**. You also need an `else` condition to cover this possible outcome.

```js
var person_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
var person_2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
var person_3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);

if ((person_1 > person_2) && (person_1 > person_3)) {
  console.log("Person 1 is highest");
}
else if ((person_2 > person_1) && (person_2 > person_1)) {
  console.log("Person 2 is highest");
}
else if ((person_3 > person_1) && (person_3 > person_2)) {
  console.log("Person 3 is highest");
}
else {
  console.log("They're all the same!");
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort and your initial variables declared as objects to help a little here.

```
// your global variables modified to be an array of objects

  var people = [
    {name: "Musa", count: 0}, 
    {name: "Zikria", count: 0}, 
    {name: "Hamza", count: 0}
]

// after you are done counting, sort the object

var sortedPeople = people.sort((a, b) => b.count > a.count))

// then just take the top person and append them in your div, no checks 

$("#first").html(`${sortedPeople[0].name}: ${sortedPeople[0].count}`)


 }
```

Just make sure you modify your counter to account for this new structure.